# Unit Test That Sends Email and Creates a new Thread

Tags: .net, unit-testing, exception

I really am feeling bad.

I have one web application that sends Emails for notifications.

It is a class that contains a basic method that sends a email like this:

```
 MailMessage email = new MailMessage();

        email.To.Add("xxx@gmail.com");

        email.Subject = "Test";
        email.Body = "t";

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        client.Send(email);
```

But i have a service called NotificatorService that verify some logic, and because this is just a "extra" the method for this service is called in a new Thread.. What i do is this:

```
public void NotifyMembers(NotificatorClientDTO clientDto) {
if(clientDto == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("clientDto");


Thread t = new Thread( 
    () => {
    // go to database, verify business rules, etc...

    // At the end if it is ok, invoke the method that sends a email
}

t.Start()
```

}

If i create a unit test that instantiates the NotificatorService and call notifyMembers with some data, the code will throw an exception but only if i execute in a seperated thread.

The thread that i create is setted at foregronnd so the system don't destroy my process i suppose.

THe exception message is this:

SmtpException: Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

I walk to 2 inner exceptions and i see this

_message    "Thread was being aborted." string

Why this is happening?
What causes the thread to be aborted?

Comment: Is this test includes any UI layer component calls? Sometimes it worth so specify MTA appartment state in test assembly config

Comment: THe service creates a new thread because i don't want block the main thread. This thread (thread that creates the deamon) will procede, and will back to an MVC application that will render a view to show to the client.

Comment: So as I supposed there is UI level is, have you tried to change AppartmentState for NUNit threads using snippet I've provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your unit test to take an `IMailService` or something similar as a dependency. Then your web application unit test doesn't need to do anything *real* in terms of sending emails - it can use a fake or a mock.

You then need to create a production implementation of `IMailService` of course - and unit testing *that* may still be challenging, but at least you'll then be *only* interested in testing mail handling, which means you may be able to change the constraints somewhat.

You can potentially do the same for the thread creation side of things. Basically, try to separate out the "nasty bits" of your code (which interact with mail services and threads) from the real logic you want to test.

Answer (score 1):

This is looks like an Integration Test rather Unit Test as you've specified in question Title.

Try out to add App.config to the Tests.Assembly project with following content and see whether it helps: (play with `ApartmentState=MTA and ApartmentState=STA`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
            <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <NUnit>
        <TestRunner>
            <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
        </TestRunner>
    </NUnit>
</configuration>
```